# Change an image on hover it with .bmp and .png image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently developing a C# WPF application and I want the image to change to another when I hover over it. Below is my code and work fine. I'm just curious that why if I put my image format as .png, the application will stop working although it had no error. How can I handle this problem in order to make the application work if I use .png image since I found that the image shown is quite pixelated when I used .bmp?

```
<Image x:Name="CloseBtn" Width="19" Height="19" Margin="457,5,11,343" MouseLeftButtonDown="CloseBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/closeIcon.bmp"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/closeIconHover.bmp"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>                    
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

Comment: still your question not clear..

Comment: Ok, my problem is I use .png image to do the image changing when mouse over it, it has no error when building the solution, when I run the application, it stops working and no result display. If I use .bmp image, everything works well, just I found that the image displayed is quite pixelated and looked not nice. So, is there any suggestion to handle the  case for .png image?

Comment: so what you are saying is that the `.png` image is displaying, but not looing nice...am I correct?

Comment: There is no issue with code, Check your Image and its location

Comment: Hi @JJJ, the .bmp image is displaying but not looking nice, for the .png image, no image (or no result) since the whole application is not working although no error in codes.

Comment: @YWah, You need to change the `Button's Template` rather than changing its `Style`

Comment: The question can't be answered from what you've shown here. The XAML is valid and works as you said. So you have to check what's wrong with you PNGs. WPF is of course able to display PNG images, so yours seem to be corrupted.